# How to print Generated Barcode ZXING in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I managed to generate a Barcode using ZXING library, now I want to print the generated barcode as it is from the ZXingBarcodeImageView with the same size ,how can I do that

```
private async Task<Item>  getItem()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage _response = await _client.GetAsync(url + txt_Barcode.Text);

        if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            
            string itemDetailes = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(itemDetailes);
             
        }
        return new Item();
    }
    private async void Btn_GetInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var selected_item = await getItem();
       
       // Item_barcode.Text = selected_item.Value;
        Item_Description.Text = selected_item.Description;
        Item_name.Text = selected_item.Name;
        Item_price.Text = selected_item.Price.ToString();
        item_barcode.BarcodeValue = selected_item.Value;
    }
```

xaml code

```
        <!--<Image HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" Margin="1" x:Name="img_barcode"></Image>-->
        <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView x:Name="item_barcode" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="100" BarcodeFormat="CODE_39" BarcodeValue="Place Barcode" >
        <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
              <zxingcomon:EncodingOptions Height="80" Width="1000"></zxingcomon:EncodingOptions>
            </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
            
        </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" >

            <Label TextColor="Black" x:Name="Item_Description"></Label>
            <Label TextColor="Black" x:Name="Item_price"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  x:Name="SLPrint" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button Text="print" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
 
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: do you mean "print" to a physical printer?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest option to do this is show the barcode inside webview.
here is a library which u can use [Link](https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/)

you can copy the script in asset folder. create a html file import the script

Now from xamarin side Evalute javascript in webview where you would send the barcode data to webview
here is how you can do it.
[Link](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2020/01/15/talking-to-your-webview-in-xamarin-forms/)

note : you dont need to do any custom rendering

with this you can remove the zxing and can make your app size small